# WinJS 2.0 Repeater Paging

Tags: repeater, windows-8.1, winjs

Does anyone know if the Paging control has Paging functionality.
The sample apps for win 8.1 did not contain such an example.

I can make a custom paging functionality ... but i wanted to know if there is an easier way.

Comment: I don't really understand your question here, e.g. what you mean by "paging functionality." Can you be more specific about the functionality you're looking for?

Comment: Something similar to this
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-loading-behaviors-718a4673

Comment: you should better give an example that people can see without having to download the code and install visual studio. you will not receive much attention if you don't make your question a bit more clear and specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "Paging control" you're referring to WinJS.UI.Pages.PageControl, then the answer is no. That control is set up to load a block of HTML into a page using DOM replacement, but doesn't provide anything more dynamic than that. The ListView is the only control that implements incremental loading behavior. So you'll need to do your own work.

Comment: Thanks Kraig ... i thought that was the case ... but being new to WinJS i just wanted to ask

Comment: Sure thing. The Repeater was created to just simplify the generation of HTML from a data source + template. It's pretty basic but powerful. I go into the details for it in my 2nd Edition free ebook, Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, which we just released yesterday. http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2. Chapter 7 talks about the Repeater in all its glory (as well as ListView and other collection controls).